# Insert data from telegram into specific column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

So i have data coming over for telegram. What should i put in the code so i can put the 3 different variables in the columns i want? Lets say i want to put new date in column A, name in column D and text in column E.
I tried some things but i know next to nothing about coding, so... yeah
This is the code

```
 var name = contents.message.from.first_name ; 
 var text = contents.message.text ; 
 var id = contents.message.from.id ;
 SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).appendRow([new Date(),name ,text ]); }`
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```gas
SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheetByName('Sheet1').appendRow(['', '', new Date(), name, text]);
```

- columnA and ColumnB are blank
- Date is in columnC
- name is in columnD
- text is in columnE

`appendRow()` appends a row to the next new line at the bottom of a sheet where there is no previous data.

Comment: hey cooper, i am sorry but how will this help me to do what i want? I want these three (new Date(),name ,text ) in a specific column.

Comment: Just like i said on my initial post. new date at column C, name at column D, and text at E. The way they come in now is A, B , C

Comment: Perhaps you can update your question to agree with your last comment.